Click en Button de Fragment que no funciona
Soy nuevo en Kotlin y estoy desarrollando una aplicacion donde debo hacer click en un boton ubicado en un fragmento pero no funciona. Realmente no consigo el error. Cualquier ayuda se agradece. El codigo es el siguiente:
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val rootView : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraccion_eyeccion_teicholz, container, false)
   val  text1 = rootView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editext1)
   val boton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.calcularfet)
    boton.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "hola",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

// Inflate the layout for this fragment
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraccion_eyeccion_teicholz, container, false)
}


Solo debes inflar en una ocasion el layout de tu Fragment o Activity, revisa mi respuesta.

El problema se debe seguramente a que estás inflando en dos ocasiones el layout fraccion_eyeccion_teicholz  de tu Fragment, lo cual es incorrecto.
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val rootView : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraccion_eyeccion_teicholz, container, false)
    ...
    ...
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraccion_eyeccion_teicholz, container, false) //*
}

Realiza el siguiente cambio solo retornando el valor de rootView que obtienes al inicio de tu mètodo onCreateView()
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val rootView : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraccion_eyeccion_teicholz, container, false)
   val  text1 = rootView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editext1)
   val boton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.calcularfet)
    boton.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "hola",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

   return rootView 
}

